# Accept requests only from authorized URLs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, url, web

I'm making a web app that will receive requests from other websites where my button was installed. But they will pass only if website URL was authorized.

How can I check from which URL request came from?

Comment: I think you are looking for [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).  I have no idea what technology you are using though since you haven't really specified.  Basically block all requests except for your "whitelist".  That link should give you some ideas.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer. Also, is your authorization concerned with A) the requests made in order to render the button, or B) the action performed upon clicking the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this situation 1) get the referrer URL and use a look up to validate. 2) Use an onclick event to get a token passed and validate against referrer 3) if your client can do a server side post on the click event of the button you desire - you can have an authentication key for validation - like an hmac authentication.